# USB vendor and product ID

Tags: usb, drivers, bluetooth, webcam

I am an embedded systems engineer and eager to learn USB. So, I started by looking at the device manager in windows to get a persepective how the usb devices are identified and what are the specific features which gets listed in windows.Later, I have used **usbview** software to get more details rather than the Device manager.

Nothing was connected to the pc before/while running the **usbview**.
Here's what I have found in usbview:

**Image 1:** corresponds to a composite device and I have looked on the web to find the company (which wasn't listed in **usbview**) using the vendor and product ID at [this link](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids). I have found the company, it is **Syntek** but product ID wasn't identified. Since Syntek had all other products related to webcam, I am assuming Syntek's product Id correponds to webcam.

**Image 2:** correponds to a Realtek bluetooth device+High Speed Chip, where I have no idea what  an high speed chip refers to.

Here are my doubts,
1) In image 1, what is the composite device refer to? If it is a webcam, does it mean webcam is connected as a USB device to my motherboard? But, why is it connected in that way?

2) In image 2, why is the Realtek bluetooth listed as a USB device? Does it mean bluetooth is connected as a USB device to my motherboard? If yes, why is it connected in that way? Finally, what is this High Speed chip?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: You're talking about a PC and a webcam, while saying nothing is connected. Is this machine a laptop? It does look like it, given the resolution and the crapload of icons in the notification area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the USB controller ("root hub") translates USB to PCI(-Express). See also [Relation between USB and PCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723481/relation-between-usb-and-pci) and [How to interpret the output of 'lsusb' — What are all these Linux Foundation root hubs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103302/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-lsusb-what-are-all-these-linux-foundation-ro) for more explanation.

So any device that can talk USB, like your webcam or a bluetooth module, can be connected internally to an USB hub.

This USB data and commands have to end up in your CPU or memory. The hubs do this by talking to the controller, which in turns talks to the rest of your machine through PCI(-Express).

Comment: So, this PCI(e) bus is connected to my main processor (in a laptop) and the usb product and vendor id's of the webcam or bluetooth are being transferred to the processor via hub--->root hub--->PCI(e)--->Main Processor. Did  I get it right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the general idea. I may have some details wrong, I'm not that deep into USB. See [Wikipedia: Bus (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing)).